# C# Interop PowerPoint - Add border to a table cell

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, office-interop, office-automation

I'm creating slides for a PowerPoint Presentation using C#. I've so far managed to create tables for a slide using Shape.AddTable method, and the table is created with a default style. I want to be able to change color and line weight for each cell, but I can't seem to find the method to add borders to the cells.

I've tried using learn.microsoft for help, but no luck:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-12/ff760048(v=office.12)

My code:

```
int n_rows = 28;
int n_cols = 8;
int row_height = 12;
int font_size = 6;
int top_margin = 1;
int left_margin = 3;

PowerPoint.Shape tb = slide.Shapes.AddTable(n_rows, n_cols, 40, 150, 870, 200);

for (int i = 1; i < n_cols + 1; i++)
{
    for(int j=1;j< n_rows + 1;j++)
    {
        tb.Table.Cell(j, i).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = font_size;
        tb.Table.Cell(j, i).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = Office.MsoTriState.msoFalse;

        tb.Table.Cell(j, i).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "test";
                        
        tb.Table.Cell(j, i).Shape.TextFrame.MarginBottom = 0;
        tb.Table.Cell(j, i).Shape.TextFrame.MarginTop = top_margin;
        tb.Table.Cell(j, i).Shape.TextFrame.MarginLeft = left_margin;
        tb.Table.Cell(j, i).Shape.TextFrame.MarginRight = 0;

        tb.Table.Cell(j, i).Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
     }
}
```

Comment: There's a hack for figuring out how to do stuff in interop. Open the file in Powerpoint and go to the developer tab. You may need to enable it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-the-developer-tab-on-the-ribbon. Start recording a a macro. Do the thing you want manually, then stop recording. The macro is recorded in VBA. Look at the VBA and it will show you what properties you need to set, which will be identical in Interop.

Comment: @ScottHannen Just that there isn't a Macro Recorder anymore in PowerPoint 2013 or newer...

Comment: That's unfortunate. I depended on that when I got stuck on things like this in Excel and Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out I had to add Dashstyle and Forecolor property to the Borders like this:

```
tb.Table.Cell(j, i).Borders[PowerPoint.PpBorderType.ppBorderTop].DashStyle = Office.MsoLineDashStyle.msoLineSolid;
tb.Table.Cell(j, i).Borders[PowerPoint.PpBorderType.ppBorderTop].ForeColor.RGB = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
tb.Table.Cell(j, i).Borders[PowerPoint.PpBorderType.ppBorderTop].Weight = 0.2f;
```

Now it works!